# Could not cast value of type 'SQLite.Blob' to 'Swift.Data'

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

This question relates to [StephenCelis Sqlite library](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift), so if someone has any idea about this, please share your fix. Though I have put my question [on the issue tracker](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/677) but haven't received any response yet, so I am also posting it here.

This is the function for creating DB record, which works fine.

```
public func createCandy(candy: Candy) throws
    {
        self.loadDb()
        let db = try self.getDB()
        let statement = try db.prepare("Insert INTO Candy(category, name, image, imageData) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)")
        try statement.run(candy.category, candy.name, candy.image, candy.impageData.datatypeValue)
    }
```

However, while retrieving data from Sqlite, I get the issue in the line `candy.impageData = row[4] as? Data`.

Following is the code for reading data

```
let candy = Candy()
candy.Id = row[0] as! Int64
candy.category = row[1] as? String
candy.name = row[2] as? String
candy.image = row[3] as? String
candy.impageData = row[4] as? Data
candies.append(candy)
```

This is the error message:

> Could not cast value of type 'SQLite.Blob' to 'Swift.Data'

Just wondering what is the appropriate class in the library for casting this.